# Is it secure to give aws credentials (accessKey and secretKey) to a code hoster like BitBucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, bitbucket

We are working on a project that is hosted on AWS.

In this project we use elastic beanstalk, relational database and web UI.

Codes are hosted on bitBucket and we set the aws accessKey and secretKey in bitBucket's environment for deploying the code to AWS.

Is this secure? is there any possibility to this credentials be stolen from bitbucket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credentials can always end up in the wrong hands, so if you give any credentials to anyone - for any purpose - always make sure they have the absolute minimum amount of access they need, i.e. just enough privileges to do what they need to do, and not a bit more.

Good practice would also suggest to rotate those credentials on a regular basis, and also to track from where and when they are being used by taking a look at your cloudtrail logs.

For example if you give a set of credentials access to a particular bucket for putting s3 objects into it - and those credentials are seen trying to start ec2 instances instead, or write to a different s3 buckets (for example), its a good chance someone else has them and is trying to see what 'else' they can do with them.

You really just can't give them out and forget about them - you need to monitor how they are being used - how often will depend on how critical your data is.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i think we should forget about the automatic deployment and do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

No, you shouldn't hardcode your AWS credentials in the application source code, this is a dangerous move that cost other AWS users a lot of money, there are some scripts that scan code hosting websites like bitBucket and others 24/7 for active and valid credentials so that they can use them for other purposes like mining or other things.

The best way to avoid this is to use **IAM Roles**.

Please check https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/Security/AWS_Security_Best_Practices.pdf